# Error when using serve modules without publishing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am getting this error when "serve modules without publishing" is checked in the application server (Tomcat) inside eclipse
When its not checked - the application is running with no issue,
The problem is that every change I make eclipse will deploy and restart tomcat,

Do I need to do anything else besides checking "serve modules without publishing"?

```
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

type Exception report

message The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:278)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:76)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:124)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:411)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1430)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.xerox.infrastructure.filters.LoginInterceptor.doFilter(LoginInterceptor.java:58)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.15 logs.
```

Comment: Is the problem that it deploys and restarts, or this log output?